# Code syntax checking using highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Some languages have flow control or loop structures that require a few words, for example, shell has

```
if [...]
then
  ...
fi
```

Is it possible to use the syntax highlighting features of vim to indicate that there is an error, if, for example a `fi` is detected before a `then`? And if it is, how to do it for that example?

Comment: I don't know if it answers your question, but there's a vim plugin called syntastic that can run your file through an external syntax checker and displays the errors it has detected : https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

Answer (score 5):

With some languages, the syntax highlighting can show an error, if the syntax rules define them. For example, the C syntax definition in my system includes an error for invalid octal numbers:

```
syn match   cOctalError display contained "0\o*[89]\d*"
```

[image]

Or in shell scripts, an unmatched `fi`:

[image]

More commonly, this is achieved via syntax checking plugins which show messages. For example, [the syntastic plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) can indicate lines with errors, and the error message given by the program used to check the syntax:

[image]

Admittedly, the error is a bit cryptic, and in some cases, can be quite long-winded. But with a bit of practice, this will help you spot errors quickly enough.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) is a lot more useful for detecting problems than `sh -n`, and it's supported by syntastic.

Comment: @lcd047 Thanks for the tip. I hope the AUR script for that doesn't make me build it. Haskell programs scare me these days.

Comment: They should.  Oh yes, they should. :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Indeed, finding an unmatched closing (like `fi`) is quite simple. However I still haven't seen how to get that middle `then` with a syntax file. I'll try the recommended plugins.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin oh, not that simple. Try a new shell script with just `an unmatched fi` in one line. Syntax highlighting in Vim is a messy business, it isn't powerful enough for a lot of things.

Comment: @muru, well I made some syntax kind of [like that](http://pastebin.com/2wvgPdh9). And it seems to work alright. At least in what I tested so far.  But indeed no middle region tests.